# ZoomRange Highstock works not correct?

Tags: max, zooming, highcharts, min, axes

I made a Highstock diagramm and got aproblem with zooming on the yAxis. 
I have a Button and 2 textfield to get the wanted min/max values for the axis. With min:0, max: 100 it works well. With min:0, max:80 it doesn't (max will still be 100 in the Diagramm).
If I use the mouse for zooming it works well (even a min of: 3.7 and a max of 3.894 is possible). But using the mouse is not an Option, because in the later Diagramm there will be 3 yAxes with individual zoom.

```
$(function () {
var seriesOptions = [],
    seriesCounter = 0,
    names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'];

/**
 * Create the chart when all data is loaded
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function createChart() {

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },
        chart:{
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        yAxis: [
        {
            labels: {
               format: '{value}',
            },
            height: '100%',
            opposite: false,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },
        ],

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    },
    function(chart){

        $('#btn').click(function(){
            var min = temp_min.value,
                max = temp_max.value;
            chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes((min),(max)); 
        });

    });
}

$.each(names, function (i, name) {

    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?',    function (data) {
                    if(seriesCounter==0){            
            seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data,
            yAxis: 0
            };
        } else {
           seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data,
            yAxis: 0
            };
        }



        // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
        // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
        seriesCounter += 1;

        if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
            createChart();
        }
    });
});
```

});

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PatrickVCP/qt0xm0x4/85/)

Another Question: Is it possible to set up a scrollbar for the yAxis as well?
Thanks for your help, Patrick

Answer (score 0):

This is related with fact that tickInterval is not regular, so is rounded to value (like 100). The solution is using tickPositioner which calculates ticks, based on extremes which you define.

```
tickPositioner: function (min,max) {
            var positions = [],
                tick = Math.floor(min),
                increment = Math.ceil((max - min) / 5);

            for (tick; tick - increment <= max; tick += increment) {
                positions.push(tick);
            }
            return positions;
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6s11kcwd/

The scrollbar is supported only for xAxis.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.