# Highcharts TickPositioner with decimals

Tags: highcharts, position, decimal, zooming

I got my Chart work with TickPositioner, but now i got another Problem. When I set the Range from min 0 to max 2 i dont get all 5 ticks on the yAxis. It doesn't show decimal values. I have many series with min of 0.9 and max of 1.05 and an yAxis with only ticks of 0,1,2 ist not very helpful.

So i want tickPositioner with Decimal values and always 10 ticks. Is that possible? What do i have to do?

The first question with answer:
[ZoomRange Highstock works not correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648919/zoomrange-highstock-works-not-correct/34652642#34652642)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6s11kcwd/

Comment: In the increment variable you divide by 5, which is number of output ticks. replace this value with 10, then you will always has 10 ticks. Second solution is usion tickAmount param. http://jsfiddle.net/6q0nk3jw/